# Laravel - Stop adding stacktrace details.

Tags: php, logging, laravel

I am just beginning with Laravel and found that whenever we get any error / exception then Laravel itself appends stacktrace results in log file.

Is there any way to stop it as I don't need it at all and it is unnecessarily increasing the log file size on production server.

Please help me to get rid off from this issue. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you can override the `App::error()` filter with something like this:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error('This is the only error message that will appear in your logs');
    if( ! (Config::get('app.debug')))
    {
         return Response::view('errors.error_page', array(), 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly for this I was looking for. You really resolved my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Where would one put this?

Answer (score 4):

Override [report()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L59) in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

Here is what I use in my projects.

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    // parent::report($exception);

    if ($this->shouldntReport($exception)) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove stack-trace when not debugging.
    if (!config('app.debug')) {
        Log::error(
            sprintf(
                "\n\r%s: %s in %s:%d\n\r",
                get_class($exception),
                $exception->getMessage(),
                $exception->getFile(),
                $exception->getLine()
            )
        );
        // 'trace' => $exception->getTraceAsString(),
    }
}
```

And I set `APP_DEBUG=false` in production.

Comment: Why both newlines and carriage-returns?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody might be strolling by and find this useful, so here is my contribution.
This is how I handled this issue.

First, I created a helper function called `logAnException` for whenever I want to handle an exception with `try-catch`, e.g.

```
try {
    // do some work        
    return redirect()->back();
}
catch (\Exception $exception) {
    // USAGE EXAMPLE
    logAnException($exception);
    return redirect()->back()->withInput( $request->except('_token') );
}
```

`logAnException` looks something like this...

```
function logAnException(\Exception $exception) {
    $exceptionFormat = "\nAppName-EXCEPTION \nMESSAGE:: %s \nFILE:: %s \nLINE::%s \n\n";

    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info(sprintf($exceptionFormat,
        // some exceptions don't come with a message
        !empty(trim($exception->getMessage()))
            ? $exception->getMessage()
            : get_class($exception),
        $exception->getFile(),
        $exception->getLine()
    ));
}
```

Error Logging in Laravel can be overridden in the `report` method of the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class. So, I just replaced the legacy `parent::report($exception);` with `logAnException($exception);` like so

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    // parent::report($exception);
    logAnException($exception);
}
```

With this, exceptions are now rendered in about just five line.